# how to update the type of session in session callback in Next-auth when using Typescript

Tags: typescript, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I am using typescript and my [...next-auth].tsx file looks like this:

```js
import NextAuth, { Awaitable, Session, User } from "next-auth";
// import GithubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

type ExtendedUserType = User & { username?: string; uid?: string };

export default NextAuth({
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signin", // for custom sign in page
  },
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token, user }): Awaitable<Session> {
      (session.user as ExtendedUserType).username = session.user?.name
        ?.split(" ")
        .join("")
        .toLocaleLowerCase();

      (session.user as ExtendedUserType).uid = token.sub;

      return session;
    },
  },
});
```

when fetching the session using the `useSession` hook I do not get Typescript autocompletion for the newly added keys - 'username', 'uid'

[image]

I am also getting this typescript error for `Awaitable<Session>` type
[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The answer to the above is discussed [here](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/2979)

TLDR; [next-auth.js.org/getting-started/typescript#module-augmentation](http://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/typescript#module-augmentation)

### Solution:

Add the following `types/**/*.ts` in `tsconfig.json`:

```js
{ 
  .
  .
  .
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "types/**/*.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Then add the following for `session.user`.

#### types/next-auth.d.ts

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth"

declare module "next-auth" {
  /**
   * Returned by `useSession`, `getSession` and received as a prop on the `SessionProvider` React Context
   */
  interface Session {
    user: {
      /** The user's name. */
      name: string
    }
  }
}
```