# error with authorize function of next-auth with ts

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

i have type error with authorize function in next-auth with CredentialsProvider

```
export const authOptions : NextAuthOptions ={
    session : { strategy: "jwt" },
    providers : [ CredentialsProvider({
        async authorize( credentials  ) {
            
            const { email , password } = credentials;
            
            try{
                await connectDB()
            } catch ( err ){
                console.log( err );
                throw new Error( ERROR.SERVER_ERROR );
            }

            if ( !email || !password ) throw new Error( ERROR.INVALID_DATA );

            const user  = await User.findOne({ email })
            if( !user ) throw new Error( ERROR.CREATE_ACCOUNT )

            const isValid = await verifyPassword( password , user.password )
            if ( !isValid ) throw new Error( ERROR.WRONG_PASSWORD )

            return { email }

        }
    })]
}

const handler = NextAuth (authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

error :

```
Type '(credentials: Record<string, string>) => Promise<{ email: string; }>' is not assignable to type '(credentials: Record<string, string>, req: Pick<RequestInternal, "body" | "query" | "headers" | "method">) => Awaitable<User>'.
  Type 'Promise<{ email: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'Awaitable<User>'.
    Type 'Promise<{ email: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<User>'.
      Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
        Type '<TResult1 = { email: string; }, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: (value: { email: string; }) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>, onrejected?: (reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type '<TResult1 = User, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: (value: User) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>, onrejected?: (reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) => PromiseLike<...>'.
          Types of parameters 'onfulfilled' and 'onfulfilled' are incompatible.
            Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
              Property 'id' is missing in type '{ email: string; }' but required in type 'User'.
```

at the end i return id with email but i have error again
authorize work but i cant build

Answer (score 0):

The return type of the authorize function is `Awaitable<User | null>`

```
authorize: (
  credentials: Record<keyof C, string> | undefined,
  req: Pick<RequestInternal, "body" | "query" | "headers" | "method">
) => Awaitable<User | null>
```

The `User` type in next-auth is

```
export interface User extends DefaultUser {}
export interface DefaultUser {
  id: string
  name?: string | null
  email?: string | null
  image?: string | null
}
```

Currently you are returning object with only one property: `email` which is of type `string`. You need to add at least the property `id` of type `string` to the returned object as it's not optional.

It is also possible to **augment NextAuth default types** to fit your needs as explained [in the NextAuth documentation.](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/typescript#module-augmentation)

Create file `types/next-auth.d.ts` with the following content

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface User {
    email: string;
  }
}
```

You may need to add `types/**/*.ts` into the tsconfig.json file as explained in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69606162/18127727)

```
{ 
  .
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "types/**/*.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  .
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the type error, you must return the object so that it appears to be Awaitable<...>, referring to the next-auth documentation [here](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/credentials#how-to).